# Seed Pylab's random number generator?

Tags: python, random, matplotlib, weibull

I've been scouring the net and documentation to no avail. I can seed `random` but not the `mtrand` generator (Mersenne Twister I believe?), no command seems to work.

```
from pylab import *

# >> seed random number generator <<
print '%.3f' % weibull(2)
print '%.3f' % weibull(2)
```

I want both of those strings to produce the same result. I am using the function in a more complicated setting, but this should suffice for my purposes.

Comment: why would weilbull return the same result if you don't seed it between calls?

Comment: `random` took a single seed to reproduce results, but you are right that seeding before every call fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seed pylab using `pylab.seed`:

```
>>> pylab.seed(0)
>>> pylab.weibull(2)
0.89211799004566095
>>> pylab.seed(0)
>>> pylab.weibull(2)
0.89211799004566095
```

Comment: Phil Cooper had already given me the answer I needed, but I'm glad to seal the question.